# Date picker dialog compatible with Marshmallow and lower versions

Tags: android

Can any one suggest me how to use date picker dialog compatible for Marshmallow and lower versions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)
compatible with kitkat to latest version